# Write entity only if the key isn't present in Google Datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

The problem I'm trying to solve is: I have a service that generates entities every day. Some of those entities will be new, and some will have already been found in a previous run.

I need to:

1. keep the database up-to-date, i.e. containing all the entities that have ever been found
2. be able to tell when a new entity is found. Each entity contains a timestamp, so if I can make sure entities aren't over-written, this shouldn't be too hard (I'll just query the database for the entities that were found today and these should be the new ones), so this is what I'm trying to do.

The generated data looks like this

```
[
{"key": "a",
"foo": "bar",
"timestamp": "EXMAPLE_TIMESTAMP" },
{"key": "b",
"foo": "baz",
"timestamp": "EXMAPLE_TIMESTAMP" }
]
```

Note: The entities have unique datastore keys

Edit: I tried using `Put()`, but it just overwrites the entities if their keys already exist, which leads to the timestamps being updated even if the actual content is the same.

Comment: What `Go` code have you tried? What seems to be the issues you're hitting?

Comment: I tried using `Put()`, but it just overwrites the entities if their keys already exist, which leads to the timestamps being updated even if the actual content is the same @colm.anseo

Comment: Cerise, my goal is to create a new entity if it doesn't exists, and *do nothing if it exists*. I don't want to update existing entities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an [insert mutation](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/datastore#NewInsert) to save the entity only if the key does not exist.

```
_, err = client.Mutate(ctx, datastore.NewInsert(key, value))
if merr, ok := err.(datastore.MultiError); ok && merr[0] == codes.AlreadyExists {
    err = nil
}
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much; this is perfect! Do you know how billing would work in this case? Like if I try to write an entity that already exists, does this count as a document write?

Comment: @DavidBryant I don't know, but my guess is that it's a small operation.  Please accept the answer if the answer solved your problem.